# Is it possible to integrate Android app with BBM on new BlackBerry 10?

Tags: android, blackberry-10, bb-messenger

There is possibility to 'convert' native Android Java app to BlackBerry (BlackBerry Runtime for Android), but is there any way to connect that app to BlackBerry 10 BBM?

Comment: Nothing has been announced by RIM: check the roadmap here: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/roadmap/

Answer (score 0):

No, not at the moment. As was posted in the comments, you can always check the [arrival boards/roadmap](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/roadmap/) although nothing has been said about BBM integration yet.